# Black Hole DNS server with individual exceptions

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I've successfully created a "Black Hole" DNS server using the instructions here: http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Creating_a_DNS_Black_Hole_for_Captive_Portal_Clients

With that, I achieved the desired behaviour: no matter which host name I lookup, I receive the same IP address from the Bind server. HOWEVER, I need to poke some holes in this setup, and the configuration of Bind is extremely obtuse to me. So my question is ...

How do I add individual exceptions to this DNS Black Hole setup? It doesn't need to forward the request, since I know exactly which address the hosts will have. So this solution can (and should) function completely autonomously, with no dependency on a downstream DNS server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you've used the example zone file from that page, just add another record which will override the wildcard.  For example, you might end up with

```
              IN          NS    .
.             IN           A    192.168.1.5
*.            IN           A    192.168.1.5
something.com IN           A      192.0.2.1    ; <-- your exception
```

Specific records will always override more general matching wildcards.